# DocumentListener with Thread.sleep

Tags: java, swing, thread-sleep, documentlistener, javax.swing.timer

I want to know when I am writing and when I am deleting, but, after a 0.5 second delay, it will tell me "You stopped writing/deleting" However, it only shows that message and it delete or write after a half second delay.

**How could I use `Thread.sleep(500);` correctly?**

My current source code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;


public class TextChangedFrame extends JFrame {

    JTextField textField = new JTextField("Put your text here");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("You have written: ");

    public TextChangedFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 100);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                label.setText("I'm writting: " + textField.getText());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                }
                label.setText("I stopped writing");
            }

            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                label.setText("I'm deleting");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                }
                label.setText("I stopped deleting");
            }

            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextChangedFrame frame = new TextChangedFrame();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Never, ever call `Thread.sleep(...)` on the Swing event dispatch thread, the EDT. Ever. Not unless you want to put the entire application to sleep.

Comment: Ow, so how can i do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. I have edited to try to clarify, but it would greatly help if you could edit your question for details. Currently, it seems that you are asking what `thread.sleep(int x)` does, which suspends any operations that the current thread is doing for `x` milliseconds (Thread.sleep(1000) = 1 second suspension).

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to do? Please clarify your problem for us. Make no assumptions about what we know about your problem.

Comment: I want to know at that label when im writing or deleting anything in the textField, BUT, after a 0,5 of writing or deleting it should say that i have stopped.

Comment: Use Swing Timers instead.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try!
And sorry for my bad english, trying to improve it.

Comment: I have expanded my comment to an answer, look at it for more clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again, use a Swing Timer to do the dirty work. What you do is whenever you edit or delete, call re-start on the Timer to re-set the timer and start it. The restart() method will stop the Timer if it is running.

```
     public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        label.setText(EDITING);
        writeDeleteTimer.restart();
     }
```

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TextChangedFrame extends JPanel {

   public static final String STOPPED_EDITING = "No Longer Editing or Deleting";
   private static final String EDITING = "Editing";
   private static final String DELETING = "Deleting";
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 500;
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = 100;
   private JTextField textField = new JTextField("Put your text here");
   private JLabel label = new JLabel("You have written: ");
   private ActionListener timerListener = new TimerListener();
   private Timer writeDeleteTimer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, timerListener);

   public TextChangedFrame() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

         public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            label.setText(EDITING);
            writeDeleteTimer.restart();
         }

         public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            label.setText(DELETING);
            writeDeleteTimer.restart();
         }

         public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
         }
      });
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         label.setText(STOPPED_EDITING);
         Timer timer = (Timer) evt.getSource();
         timer.stop();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TextChangedFrame mainPanel = new TextChangedFrame();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextChangedFrame");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

---

Answer edited: no need to recreate the Timer object. Simply call `restart()` on it as it will stop the current Timer if it's running.

Comment: Thanks! It was what i was looking for!
It works correctly! :)

Comment: @David: please see edit and simplification of code. No need to re-create the Timer all the time. Simply call `restart()` on it.

Answer (score 2):

This question is fairly poor, and is not very clear, so I cannot give an exact answer until the question is cleared up.

It seems currently that you are using `Thread.sleep(500)` to cause a delay for 500 milliseconds. In most programs, this will work.

`Thread.sleep(int x)` suspends (or freezes, depending on who you ask) the current operation for `x` milliseconds (in your case, 500 milliseconds).

In the application you are using, you are using it to suspend a change in text. Due to it's location, it currently freezes the entire swing box, and it is not recovering.

If you HAVE to use `Thread.sleep(int x)`, then I would recommend that you save the text you are using as a String, then update the `TextChangedFrame` after you update the String. This allows you to suspend operations, without suspending the `TextChangedFrame`.

PsuedoCode:

```
String oldString = "old string";
String newString = "new string";

// setup your dialog/popup here, with oldString

Thread.sleep(500);

// modify the dialog/popup here, changing oldString to newString
```

and that should avoid any freezing issues. (which I think, with the question and comments, your problem is).

**A better solution would be to use [Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), as mentioned by [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362716/documentlistener-with-thread-sleep#comment23444699_16362716)**

Comment: I'll try `Swing timers`! Thanks